# Need to automatically rotate the result of a view once a week (Sunday night)

Tags: views, rules, entities, flags

The view (block) displays content (field collection items) on my home page.  I had it set so the client could choose what to display by checking a boolean field.  The view works fine, but now the client has decided they would like the content to be chosen randomly and for it to be automated (to change on a weekly basis).  I need every user to see the same content displayed and I need the same content to stay up a whole week.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  I've tried setting the display to show only 1 and sort on random with the view cache set to 6 days/6 days.  I'm just not sure how reliable this will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use rules module with rules scheduler to toggle the "Promoted to front page" flag on content of that type? So every Sunday a rule would fire that demotes the current one, promotes the next one, and schedules the next few of these cycles? You should be able to get something neat working with this approach.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using data from a field collection so using 'Promoted to front page' isn't an option.

Comment: I believe that my approach will still work if you use flag module on a field collection item and have rules flag/unflag instead of using core's promoted feature.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that solution is it relies on the view's cache lifetime which might not sync up to Sunday (e.g. a manual cache clear it will reset the lifetime clock on the view cache and expire it 6 days from the manual cache clear).

A better solution would rely on [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) and do the following:

- Trigger every Sunday
- Set all node fields to false
- Randomly select a node and update its field to true.

This could be accomplished with a custom module hook_cron or, I think, the [Elysia Cron module](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron).